# how to reset RoamingSettings Key when outlook web addin is removed

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

i am trying to build outlook web addin - mailapp  (task pane )
so  to perform my required operations i need to keep some data in `roamingSettings` like below

```
Office.context.roamingSettings.set(key, value); 
  Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync((result) => {
  // result:
  if (result.error) {
    
  // console.log(result.error.message);
 }
```

since this is mailbox app, i would required this data when next time user opens up my addin
but the issue i am facing is when user would uninstall/Removes this Web addin i need to clear key value pair whatever was set in `roamingSettings`  and for removing key value i know the code which is
`roamingSettings.remove` and `saveasync` but i dont know how to do this when addin is being removed. Pls Help!!

Comment: There's no hook to run addin/developer code when an addin is removed. Could you tell more about the scenario on why you want to remove the roamingSettings? Is it for cleaning up data or are there more specific reasons? Also if it matters, a user may disable vs remove an addin - would you want to remove the settings for both cases?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT thanks for responding, yes it is for cleaning up data ii dont want data to be available when addin is removed.and also i got the scenario where user may remove addin and add again later. so when user adds it again i am still getting old data from roaming settings. if there is no hook/event when addin is removed is there any work around,

Comment: i need to do it only in case of remove addins

Comment: pls helpme,  i searched everywhere i would like to know is there any way to get manifest file element value lets say DisplayName element in javasript  code (via officejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the feature of clearing roaming settings on uninstall of an add-in, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process